# How to change the indentation of sub menu items in a NavigationView?

Tags: android, menu, material-design, submenu

When we define a NavigationView with a section with sub menu items. It left aligns the sub items with the section title:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

[image]

I tried adding a transparent image with the correct size to pad:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_transparent"
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_transparent"
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

[image]

But by default the NavigationView:

1. Adds a fixed padding between the icon the text
2. Enforces a fixes size on the icon itself

I could not find how to configure this padding nor the icon size.

**Question** How can we change the sub item indentation so that the sub items are more indented?

I prefer to do it cleaning via an attribute rather than inserting transparent images.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I have not looked into this since I posted it. Need to wrap up other higher priority work. 

But I am starting to think that maybe it is not the better design to have the indentation - after all I did not see it recommended in the Material Design guidelines. 

I will be looking into this again in the next couple of weeks. So I will post an update then.

Comment: @Noundla After looking into this again, I did not find a way to do it. My current take on this is that indentation is not promoted within the Material Design guidelines so I do not consider it a best practice in Android therefore I am staying away from it. 

Instead, a better approach is to use the background and foreground colors of each menu row to indicate grouping. I have seen that done nicely in a number of apps. FYI what I mean by foreground color is the text color. You can also integrate font types to emphasize different aspects of the grouping and state.

Answer (score 9):

**Disclaimer**

See my comment to Noundla on the main question where I explain why I think that indentation is not the right approach.

**Answer**

With that said, if you **must** have indentation the simplest way is to pad each menu item with spaces. This is not ideal but it is simple to implement, understand and replace when a better option is available. And it works with the built-in Android *NavigationView* without having to introduce external libraries:

Here is the code sample that will work:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item android:title="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Sub item 1" />
        <item android:title="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
   </item>
</menu>
```

I hope this saves someone out there time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got the answer but I had the same problem and ended up using MaterialDrawer - https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer.

You need to extend the SecondaryDrawerItem and add the padding <s>on bindView</s> onPostBindView.

```
drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeader(drawerHeader)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item1"),
                    new CustomSecondaryDrawerItem().withName("SubItem1"),
                    new CustomSecondaryDrawerItem().withName("SubItem2")
            )
            .build();
```

**CustomDrawerSecondaryItem.java**

```
public class CustomSecondaryDrawerItem extends SecondaryDrawerItem {

   @Override
   public void onPostBindView(IDrawerItem drawerItem, View view) {

       Context ctx = view.getContext();

       int paddingLeft = ctx.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.drawer_secondary_item_padding_left);
       view.setPadding(paddingLeft, view.getPaddingTop(), view.getPaddingRight(), view.getPaddingBottom());

       super.onPostBindView(drawerItem, view);

   }
}
```