# How to obtain Play Store like navigationView?

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm trying to obtain this result with the navigationView. I would like to have a submenu like "le mie app e i miei giochi" in the picture.[image]

This is my code:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_museum"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_museum"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_floor"
        android:title="@string/museum"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_opere"
        android:title="@string/opere"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_paintings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_autori"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_author"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_collections"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_photolibrary"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_events"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_scan"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_scan"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favs"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_full_star"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_info"
        android:title="@string/museum"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"/>

</group>
```

and this is the result:[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take your time to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Comment: Is there something wrong in my question?

Comment: Is there anything good in your question?

Comment: I've added my code! Now is better?

Comment: Yes, it's somehow better, now. But what is the question about, then? The background color?

Comment: In the google menu the item "Le mie app e i miei giochi" has a left margin. It is like a submenu that appears only when you click on the super menu..I would to obtain the same effect in my menu. "Museo" is my supermenu and "Piani" the submenu!

Comment: Maybe they use an `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: This page may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528998/how-to-change-the-indentation-of-sub-menu-items-in-a-navigationview

Answer (score 1):

The code is

```
<code><item android: title="Le mie app e i miei giochi" /><\code>
```

I tested by myself and it's working perfectly.